# c# windows services bring up gui

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, service

I have a c# standalone application. i want to bring up the application GUI when the computer starts and minimize it to the system tray.
we know that using windows services we cannot bring up the GUI as it doesn't run on user profile.

my question is : how does some applications like 'McAfee' and others runs on local system on system start with GUI ?
is there any way to make our application run like that with GUI on system startup ?

Answer (score 3):

They use a separate application and have a communication channel between the *GUI Application* and the *Service*

This is the most widely accepted approach.

You can use many *IPC* ways to communicate between the *Service* and the *GUI Application*, when your user logs in you just set your *GUI Application* to run on startup, it then contacts the *Service* for information and is able to send commands and so-forth

**Update**

Programs that "need" to run as a *Service* (and you need to determine that) and have a user interface *GUI* use *IPC* to communicate with each other. They can actually be the same application if you get fancy (and can be started as a service or a GUI), however they can be completely separate applications if you choose.

In both cases, there needs to be a way of communicating between the 2 processes, you could use `NamedPipes`, or `WCF`, or other `IPC` techniques to achieve this.

You can find some more IPC techniques here

[Interprocess Communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

More info on services

[Introduction to Windows Service Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications)

However, you really need to work out whether need *Service* to achieve your desired behaviour. *i.e Do you need to run on a special system account, do you need to run when users are logged off, ect...*

Comment: separate application means ? all the exe's of McAfee are residing in the machine isn't it. Can you please elaborate 'separate application' and 'communication channel'. I actually have no idea of how they do it. can we too do the same way for our application ?